# Is there any reason to not use exceptions to test if an element exists in a std::map

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, dictionary, stl

I've recently started using c++11 for a number of projects and have also started heavily using the stl containers which I'm relatively new to.

I have a function I've recently written which does something similar to this:

```
CMyClass* CreateAndOrGetClass( int _iObjectId, std::map<int, CMyClass*>& _mapObjectData )
{
    CMyClass* pClassInstance{ nullptr };

    try
    {
        pClassInstance = _mapObjectData.at( _iObjectId);
    }
    catch ( ... )
    {
        pClassInstance = new CMyClass();
        __mapObjectData.insert( _iObjectId, pClassInstance );
    }

    return ( pClassInstance );
}
```

My question is about using exceptions for what clearly aren't 'exceptional' conditions.  It seems like a very concise way of achieving the purpose at hand, rather than involving setting up iterators.

Are there any gotchas about using exceptions for this type of purpose that I might be missing?

---

**Measurements***

So to follow up, I did some performance tests comparing my exception based code to the code example in the selected answer.  It was a good exercise to go through and qualifies the suggestions of bad performance using exceptions for the normal flow of code.  It also gave some good reference material for the assertion of near zero performance loss when exceptions aren't thrown.

Although these tests weren't exhaustive, here's what I observed:

Each test was run over a large number of insert/fetches using rand() as the source of the map key (which generated the maximum 32768 elements):

Exception method: average 5.99 seconds
Find/add method: average 0.75 seconds

Increasing the scope of the random elements tenfold gave back these numbers:

Exception method: average 56.7 seconds
Find/add method: average 4.54 seconds

I then prefilled the map with all possible key entries so that the try never threw:

Exception method: average 0.162 seconds
Find/add method: average 0.158 seconds

Curiously, with MS VStudio, debug mode code was faster with the exception handling method.

Comment: Your code will be slower, much harder to debug, and certainly more obtuse to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exception are a means of cleanly separating failure handling from normal case code.

In your code they’re used for normal case, which defeats the purpose and has no advantage.

In the particular case at hand use `[]` indexing, which automatically inserts the key if it isn’t there already. And more generally use conditional constructs for simple conditional control flow. There *are* some exceptional cases where exceptions make sense for expressing normal case control flow (e.g. returning a result from a deeply nested recursive call), in the sense that the code can become simpler and more clear, but these exceptional cases are … exceptional.

---

Regarding efficiency, throwing an exception is costly because C++ compilers are optimized for using exceptions only for failure handling, which is assumed to be *rare*.

When failure becomes the norm, reconsider the working definition of failure.

However, just having the possibility of an exception being thrown has very little, down to 0, overhead. So you should not be afraid of using exceptions to get that failure handling safely and non-distractingly tucked away from the normal case code. Used properly, with this division of code into normal case and failure, exceptions are win-win.

---

In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847722/is-there-any-reason-to-not-use-exceptions-to-test-if-an-element-exists-in-a-std/24847883#comment38582841_24847817) to another answer you remark,

> **”** Although I like the brevity of this, it potentially leaves the map with a nullptr if the class can't be instantiated.

Well *that* is a failure situation, where using exception handling is the correct approach.

For example,

```
Your_class* creative_at( int const id, std::map<int, YourClass*>& object_data )
{
    // Basic non-creating at:
    {
        auto const it = object_data.find( id );
        if( it != object_data.end() ) { return it->second; }
    }

    // Create:
    std::unique_ptr<Your_class> p( new Your_class() );    // May throw.
    object_data[id] = p.get();                            // May throw.
    return p.release();
}
```

This code is exception based, but there is not a `try-catch` in sight.

Instead of the Java approach of manual `try-catch-finally`, in C++ one mainly lets destructors do *automatic cleanup*, such as in this case the `std::unique_ptr` destructor; this approach is called **RAII**, short for *Resource Acquisition Is Initialization*.

Comment: This is an excellent example.  I like the use of the unique_ptr to control the possible exceptions during the creation and assignment.

Comment: FWIW I am fairly familiar with c++ and have used it for quite some time and have recently read the 4th edition of Bjarne's book to get up to speed with the latest tech.  And it is from that book that I've really taken on board the constant recommendation of measuring, which this thread just shouldn't be without.  Turns out that the exception method I originally posted is about 80x slower than this method on my system (on Win7 with 32 bit release build).

Answer (score 4):

Compilers typically use a strategy for implementing exceptions that has zero runtime overhead as long as none are thrown, but if an exception is thrown, then it affects your program's performance due to the exception processing mechanism which must unwind the stack.

Even if this is acceptable for your use case, there's simply no advantage to using exceptions to manage control flow in your case. Using `map::find` is not only more succinct, but also more idiomatic.

```
auto iter = _mapObjectData.find(_iObjectId);
if(iter == _mapObjectData.end()) {
  auto instance = new CMyClass();
  _mapObjectData.insert(std::make_pair(_iObjectId, instance));
  return instance;
}
return iter->second;
```

---

@Mehrdad has a [good suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847722/is-there-any-reason-to-not-use-exceptions-to-test-if-an-element-exists-in-a-std#comment38583049_24847776) in the comments to use [`map::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound) to locate the key instead of `map::find`. The benefit would be that if the key doesn't exist the return value can be used as a *hint* for `map::insert`, which should result in better insertion performance.

```
auto iter = _mapObjectData.lower_bound(_iObjectId);
if(iter == _mapObjectData.end() || iter->first != _iObjectId) {
  auto instance = new CMyClass();
  _mapObjectData.insert(iter, std::make_pair(_iObjectId, instance));
  return instance;
}
return iter->second;
```

---

I also strongly recommend changing the type of your map from

```
std::map<int, CMyClass*>
```

to

```
std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<CMyClass>>
```

Sticking raw pointers that own resources into standard library containers is usually more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @T.C. Thank you. The perils of posting code without compiling it :)

Comment: Thanks.  Funny, that code looks exactly like what I just wrote up as the non-exception version because I want to measure if there's any difference.  My bigger concern is really what you've said though, and part of my question of using exceptions for flow control rather than their stated reason.

Comment: @Praetorian: You should be using `lower_bound` instead of `find` (but don't forget to check the key a second time to make sure it's the right key). Furthermore I think `_mapObjectData.insert(_iObjectId, instance)` doesn't even work :-) you should be passing it a `pair` (possibly along with an iterator to avoid a second lookup, which is hopefully one that you'll get back from `lower_bound`).

Comment: Leaks memory if `insert` throws.

Comment: @Mehrdad Thank you for spotting the `map::insert` error, I copied the OP's code without a second thought. I added the `lower_bound` suggestion to the answer.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Of course it does. That's why I added the suggestion to use a `unique_ptr` at the end.

Answer (score 3):

There is a reason in C++ to avoid using too much exceptions: exception processing is heavy (because all the destructors of local variables in all intermediate call frames have to be executed).

In *Ocaml* exception processing is lightweight, so they are more likely to be used like you suggest.

In your example I would rather use the [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/) member function of `std::map`

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I'm really looking for advice specifically in this type of circumstance where the exception is contained in the scope of the test.  Generally I've been avoiding exceptions due to the lack of enforcement in the language for catching them when they are thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because neither propagating the exception *nor your code itself* is particularly efficient.

Ignoring the fact that you shouldn't be storing raw pointers in the first place, the next-most-correct **and most efficient** (and readable!) way to do what you're doing is to use `operator[]`:

```
CMyClass* CreateAndOrGetClass(int _iObjectId, std::map<int, CMyClass*>& _mapObjectData)
{
    CMyClass* &pClassInstance = _mapObjectData[_iObjectId];
    if (!pClassInstance) { pClassInstance = new CMyClass(); }
    return pClassInstance;
}
```

This way, the lookup in the map is only done *once*, and the value is constructed in-place.

If course, in reality you should probably just store a `CMyClass` as the value, not `CMyClass *`, but that's independent of the point of my answer here.

Comment: This will do `new` for null pointers which already existed in the map  (OP's code didn't, although it's unclear whether that was intentional)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Good catch, but I don't expect the OP intended nulls to be valid values in the map.

Comment: Although I like the brevity of this, it potentially leaves the map with a nullptr if the class can't be instantiated.  @Matt, I specifically don't want nullptrs in the map, which would be bundled up in an exception being thrown from new failing.  

And FWIW, the raw pointer usage is deliberate and understood, so no need to add that as part of any answers.

Comment: @jgibbs: Is a different procedure also accessing the map too? Because to me it looks like this procedure would be the only one accessing the map, and in that scenario, you wouldn't need to worry about the null being there, because it won't adversely affect anything.

Comment: @jgibbs: Furthermore, I don't even understand your concern: if you're worried about the class not being instantiated correctly, then that means you want your code to be exception-safe (exceptions are the only way the code can abort in the middle and leave a dangling null in the map). But if you're worried about exceptions getting thrown, then your code already has much *bigger* problems (the raw pointer, which you already seem to be aware of), which you're completely ignoring. The dangling null in the map is going to be the least of your concerns compared to the leak that you're disregarding.

Comment: The dangling null was more of a side issue based on the fact that a failing 'new' might be unrecoverable, even expected if a class intentionally failed from missing data.  This method adds an element to the map which then needs to be checked for later if the map needs to be iterated over.

And in my case, yes other procs are accessing the map, otherwise I wouldn't be putting this data into it.  It just happens that where I'm using this function, the caller needs to use the item immediately so wrapping up the get/create together makes sense in this context.

Comment: @jgibbs: Well if it's really an issue that concerns you (and it shouldn't be, until you fix the much bigger problems in your code) then see my comment on Praetorian's answer.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by others, exceptions are slow then thrown/catched.

But it does not mean the alternative must be ugly.

```
if(!mymap.count(objectId))
{

}
```

Tells you whether your object is missing.

Also, are you sure you need pointers at all for the map values? The only resons to do that is if your class' copy constructor is very slow, or the class is not copyable/movable. Even in that case, you'll want to use `unique-ptr` or `shared-ptr`

Also, your version of hungarian notation, with prefixes like C, underscore i, p, etc is becoming less and less popular. Many people recognize it's more trouble than help. See Alexandescu & Sutter's C++ Coding standards, Chapter 0.

Comment: I am only really interested in exploring the overheads and issues surrounding the use of the exception handling.  I understand the reason for/against use of raw pointers and had I put these in my example it wouldn't have changed the question I was looking for the answer to, but thanks anyway for the advice.

Some of the artefacts of the hungarian notation methodology are still extremely useful, some of which we choose to use to the benefit of all our devs.  I have personally never found trouble using the useful bits.